# How to prevent navbar jerking?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a small personal project and i have a small issue that i'm not sure how to solve. I use `Bootstrap4` , `ejs templating engine` and `express`.My project has a Navbar where i  show **Sign in** if user is not signed in and **Account** in the opposite case.

Here is a relevant part of the Navbar:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
    <li class="nav-item  navbar-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item navbar-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Some link </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item navbar-item " id="nav-signIn">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/signIn">Sign in</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown  navbar-item" id="nav-account">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Account
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the function that controls what to show on the client side:

```
  function displayAccountOrSignIn() {
    if (!document.cookie.split(';').filter((item) => item.includes('logedIn=')).length) {
      document.querySelector('#nav-account').style.display = 'none'
    }
    else {
      document.querySelector('#nav-signIn').style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
```

My problem is that Navbar is 'jerking' because it first loads HTML and then hides what should not be displayed. I can fix it by checking cookies on the server and then conditionally  render parts of Navbar, but  i don't think it's a good idea to  do so. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you do it with CSS? Like `#nav-account, #nav-SignIn { display: none; }`. If you put that in a `style` tag in your `head`, it should work.

Comment: @grooveplex thanks, but i'm not sure what you mean. I need to display either one of them.

Comment: Right, and then once the page is loaded, you can show either one using your original code. I assume the reason why you see both is because of the time spent downloading, parsing and executing JavaScript in the context of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options here.  To know which one to recommend, we'd probably need to play with your actual site and try a few things.  All will work and prevent showing something that shouldn't be seen, some may display sooner.

1. Have all conditional content hidden first (so nothing ever displays that shouldn't) and then enable display of appropriate parts using your conditional Javascript.
2. Hide the whole toolbar by default in the HTML until you have run your conditional code and then show the whole toolbar only once its state is finalized at the end of your Javascript.  If desired, you can make the toolbar be `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none` so that it still takes up the appropriate vertical height and doesn't cause other content to shift down when it is finally  displayed.
3. Run your conditional script inline in an inline `<script>` tag immediately after the toolbar HTML.  This will ensure that the script runs ASAP after the toolbar HTML is available.  You can combine this with either #1 or #2 above.
4. Determine the proper toolbar server-side so that the HTML that arrives at the browser is already properly pre-formed.  Since the server already knows whether the user is logged in or not, this should be possible.

Comment: thank you, i've  implemented already server side conditional rendering. But i might change it now that i see more ways to do so.